# System.Net.WebClient doesn't seem to pick up HTTP Redirect?

Tags: vb.net, url, redirect, download, webclient

I'm trying to download a file in vb.net but the url I'm downloading from redirects to a generated url
like this

```
http://site/yR38aqlDhpV5?token=ykfID
```

to this:

```
http://site/yR38aqlDhpV5.128.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBHW5FB4ERKUQUOQ
```

but the web client doesn't seem to pick this up.  Is there any way around this?

```
Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
            client.DownloadFile(url, sfd.FileName)
            MsgBox("downloaded successfully!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not an answer but what exactly seems to be the issue? Does your code throw an exception or does it simply not download the file?

I quickly knocked up the exact same code in C# and attempted to download a file from a little Python web server I wrote (which I configured to issue a 301 HTTP response with a new location header,) and the file was downloaded successfully.

Within the WebClient class, an HttpWebRequest object is instantiated which handles all interactions with the HTTP protocol. It has a property called 'AllowAutoRedirect', which is set to true by defaut; thus it should handle re-directs gracefully.

You can verify this either within reflector or within the MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx